# Effective ways to hide your IP address and Device Information from apps on Mobile?

Tags: vpn, mobile, proxy, ip, iphone

How can you make sure site admins are not able to get information like your IP, Browser, Device, etc?

Comment: Is not allowing them to install their software an option? Also, what is a site admin in this case?

Comment: @Ghedipunk No, that's not, I'm running an app(Reddit) but want the IP hidden, the site admins are paid employees of Reddit.

Comment: @Ghedipunk got Nord Running but it drops coverage at times and apparently those split seconds are able to trigger their system.

Comment: @Marinate How is NordVPN (or any VPN provider for that matter) knowing your entire traffic better than Reddit knowing your IP address?

Comment: @MechMK1 it matters if your IP has been banned and you are trying to bypass their restrictions...

Comment: You have your answer: the VPN works. Have you tried going to places that offer wifi?

Comment: @schroeder Which also happens to try to break the security of a specific system, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @schroeder I do not. VPN is not working if it drops connection and the kill switch isn't activating. I'm on wifi at home and on campus.

Comment: But the VPN masks your IP successfully. That's your answer. The fact that you are having reliability problems is a separate issue.